# Is my Raspberry Pi original?

Tags: pi-4, power-supply

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. This is the first time I have bought a Raspberry Pi. As per my understanding, the recommended power supply is 5.1V / 3A. I am using a different power supply that can deliver up to 5.1V / 2.7A. However, the Pi doesn't seem to draw more than 1.25A on average with a fan on GPIO and one USB device connected. Even with stress test (stressberry), the maximum current draw was around 1.7A.

Is my Pi 4 original or is it some fake with under-powered fake components?

PS: I am measuring the current draw with an in-line USB power meter.

Comment: Why do you think that any electrical device should draw all the current that the PSU can supply?   It makes no sense to supply a PSU that can just power the target equipment.

Comment: @Chenmunka I understand that the device is not expected to draw the max current at all times. After looking at the documentation suggested by Seamus, I understand now that the 3.0 A will be required in only extreme cases and my RasPi's current draw is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your Raspberry Pi draws less than the recommended 3A power supply cannot be taken as even a weak indication that your RPi is not a genuine article. If you take a look at the [RPi documentation covering power supplies](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#power-supply), you'll see some figures that should put your mind at ease.